# Need for a P4VS tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just asked this question: [Blue question mark on files in solution explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378974/p4vs-blue-question-mark-on-files-in-solution-explorer).

SO doesn't want me to add a new [p4vs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p4vs) tag for it, and suggests using [p4v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p4v) instead:

[image]

The thing is those are two separate things: [P4V](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-client) is the Perforce Visual Client (a classic source control GUI), while [P4VS](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/visual-studio-plug-in) is an integrated Visual Studio plugin.

Should we have a dedicated tag? Or is it too specific and should the [perforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perforce) tag be used instead?

Comment: "*SO doesn't want me to add*" who is SO here? Users? The system?

Comment: @Stijn the system. The tag resembles the existing [tag:p4v] tag so I can't add it: I suppose this is to prevent people from accidentally adding new tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `p4vs` tag sounds appropriate; there are [10 hits on the keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22p4vs%22) (of which 4 are questions).

It should be a separate tag since this covers a different software package.

It'll take a moderator however to create the tag because the system protects against plural vs. singular tags.

Comment: Little typo on the tag name: it should read [tag:p4vs], not [tag:pv4s].

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou: yup, and I am not allowed to create the correct spelling either, it'll take a moderator then.

Comment: Oh I see. Well, I'm OK to create a tag wiki for it but should I wait for the rename?

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou: we can't until the tag is created, so you'll have to wait.

Comment: OK then, fair enough.

Comment: 10 hits sounds pretty small to me; what's the threshold for tag creation?

Comment: @Richard there is no treshold AFAIK.

Answer (score 6):

I don’t see the point of this as a new tag; just using the [Perforce] and [visual-studio] tag together would do the job and is much more likely to get used.

(I used Perforce for a few years, but this is the first I know about the visual-studio integration being called p4vs, so how many people asking questions will even think of using it as a tag.)

Comment: I agree, there's no `git-vs` or `git-windows` tags.